# Can't connect to certain website when connect to VPN

Tags: networking, server, dns, vpn, openvpn

please edit my text:

Here is my current operating system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

When I connect to the VPN, I encounter difficulties accessing several websites, including github.com. I have tried the following solutions, but the issue persists:

1. update related packages

```
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

2. Change DNS by adding these lines to /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

3. clear cache in google chrome
4. restart the network manager

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
```

It's worth noting that I have successfully used the same VPN on a Windows system without any issues. This suggests that the problem may be on the client side rather than the server side. Can someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes these problems are MTU size-related. Please [edit] your question and give information about the VPN provider, if you are able to `traceroute` the problematic web site, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This last solution finally worked for me:

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo reboot
```